# The given path's format is not supported in IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I want to save a uploaded excel file in asp.net. In Chrome this works good:

```
if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
{
    var currentUser = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var file = Request.Files[0];

    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = string.Format(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH_mm_ss_") + file.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Documents/"), string.Format("{0}", fileName));
        file.SaveAs(path);
        uploadModel.Document = fileName;
    }
}
```

In Chrome is the var fileName "2015-06-29 14_33_53_example.xlsx" and in IE the fileName is "2015-06-29 14_21_00_C:\example.xlsx". And throw the error by executing file.SaveAs(path);

How can I support IE?

Comment: So i can do nothing? because i've tested in IE and Chrome. And in chrome it works well and only when i use IE it throws the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using [System.IO.Path.GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to parse out the full path that IE sends. This should work on all browsers:

```
var parsedFileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
var fileName = string.Format(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH_mm_ss_") + parsedFileName );
```

[Here is a link to a MSDN blog detailing the issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2009/07/27/uploading-a-file-using-fileupload-control-fails-in-ie8.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently IE is giving you the complete path. Use `System.IO.Path.GetFileName()` method to extract the filename only:

```
var fileName = string.Format(
    DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH_mm_ss_") + 
    Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
```

For more information on `GetFileName()` have a look at the [MSDN documentation on Path.GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx). If the parameter is only a filename, the return value will be the filename itself.